# Prevent cyclone from evaluating Handlebar's template

Tags: python, twisted, tornado, handlebars.js, cyclone

How do I prevent Cyclone from converting the code? I mean, I want this line to be transfered as such to the browser so that Handlebar.js can use this as a template.

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    My firstName is {{Employee.firstName}}
</script>
```

{{Employee.firstName}} should be evaluated on the client-side. But my cyclone server tries to evaluate it on server-side and throws up an error. How do I prevent this from happening and sending it to the browser as such? The code given above is what I want in the browser-side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found the answer myself.
looks like, I have to add an exclamation mark (!) as shown below from preventing cyclone evaluating the template. Like this,

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    My firstName is {{!Employee.firstName}}
</script>
```

There it is.

Comment: In that case, handlebars is ignoring it as well!

Answer (score 3):

You should also consider not mixing your Handlebars and your Tornado/Cyclone templates in the same file.  You could also just read the file, and return it and let the client do all of the rendering.